# Select após resultado de select

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer o select em uma tabela para exibir uma lista de atividades.

E segundo select em cada uma das linhas do primeiro select para contar quantos estão em cada status, porém estou tendo erro de syntax, o que estou fazendo de errado ?

```
SELECT ATIVIDADE, DEPARTAMENTO,
(
    SELECT 
    COUNT(STATUS WHERE STATUS = 'PENDENTE' OR STATUS = 'INICIADO' OR  STATUS = 'INICIADO/VENCIDO') AS AFAZER,
    COUNT(STATUS WHERE STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO') AS FEITO,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    WHERE DT_VENCIMENTO BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'
    FROM LISTA_DE_ATIVIDADES
)
FROM TIPOS_DE_ATIVIDADE
```

Desta forma abaixo eu consegui retornar 1 único registro, porém são vários e com os valores errados.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TIPO_ATIVIDADE AS ATIVIDADE, DEPARTAMENTO,
(SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (STATUS = 'PENDENTE' OR STATUS = 'INICIADO' OR STATUS = 'INICIADO/VENCIDO') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))  AS AFAZER,
(SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS FEITO,
(SELECT COUNT(*)) AS TOTAL
FROM tbl_atividades;
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio que faltou uma vírgula antes do SELECT mais interno. Não lhe parece estranho que você deseje um campo, no caso STATUS, que possua ao mesmo tempo o conteúdo "PENDENTE", "INICIADO" e "INICIADO/VENCIDO"? Aliás você não deveria utilizar ' no lugar de "?

Comment: Corrigi a query, porém continua nao funcionando, editei com a nova atualização

Comment: Você está utilizando a sintaxe errada na função COUNT. Tente: COUNT(CASE WHEN (STATUS = 'PENDENTE' OR STATUS = 'INICIADO' OR  STATUS = 'INICIADO/VENCIDO') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AFAZER,
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FEITO,

Comment: Note também que a cláusula WHERE vem depois da cláusula FROM.

Comment: editei a postagem tentei de uma nova forma usando o metodo que voce falou, nao sei se apliquei corretamente, consegui retornar um unico registro

Comment: Acrescente o erro que você está recebendo

Comment: Você não teria que relacionar pelo menos a ATIVIDADE do SELECT mais externo (tabela TIPOS_DE_ATIVIDADE) com o SELECT mais interno (tabela LISTA_DE_ATIVIDADES)?

Comment: Desta segunda forma que me foi passado , a query trouxe um unico registro , e com o somatorio incorreto.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Para sua query funcionar faltava só utilizar o **GROUP BY**.

Tomei a liberdade de editar a query  visando também o ganho de performance. Utilize dessa maneira, deve funcionar

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  TIPO_ATIVIDADE AS ATIVIDADE, 
  DEPARTAMENTO,
  SUM(IF(STATUS IN ('PENDENTE', 'INICIADO', 'INICIADO/VENCIDO'), 1, 0)) AS AFAZER,
  SUM(IF(STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO', 1, 0)) AS FEITO,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM 
  tbl_atividades
GROUP BY 
  TIPO_ATIVIDADE,
  DEPARTAMENTO
;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu o problema